# Listing column dependencies

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, foreign-key, metadata, dependencies

I want to alter the datatype of a table column from `varchar(x)` to `varchar(y)`.

To do that, I need to know what dependencies there are on this column.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

There are so many things outside of SQL Server's metadata that may depend on the size of a column, it's not even funny. Here are a few things you'll need to check:

- Any variable or parameter declarations in stored procedures, dynamic SQL or ad hoc SQL that may pass values to that column, filter on it, search from it, or get assigned from it.
- Any references to the column in triggers, check constraints, default constraints, etc.
- Any related columns that are used in joins, `IN`, `NOT IN`, `EXISTS`, `NOT EXISTS`, `EXCEPT`, `UNION`, etc.
- Any T-SQL code that implicitly relies on the old length, e.g. `LEFT(some_string, old_length)`.
- Any variable or parameter declarations in client-side application code that dictates the length of the string, directly or indirectly.
- Any user who regularly creates ad hoc code on their own machine and "remembers" the length of that column.

I'm going to presume that your `varchar(x)` column is not a key and is not declared as unique (if it is, you can also check `sys.foreign_keys` for any references to them).

Note that if you make the column bigger then any code that currently assumes the old length with potentially still work without error. Let's say X is 10 and Y is 20. Old code that assumes 10 might say this:

```
DECLARE @foo VARCHAR(10) = '01234567890123456789';
PRINT @foo;
```

Result:

```
0123456789
```

Silent truncation, no error. Same for this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo 
  @foo VARCHAR(20) -- correct length
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @variable VARCHAR(10); -- old length
  SET @variable = @foo;
  PRINT @variable;
END
GO
```

Sorry, but there is no magic query that will round up all of these things for you. You will need to manually inspect any code that references this table. In SQL Server stored procedures, at least, this should be easy:

```
SELECT [schema] = s.name, [object] = o.name, o.[type_desc]
  FROM sys.objects AS o
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS d
  ON o.[object_id] = d.referencing_id
  WHERE d.referenced_schema_name = N'dbo'
    AND d.referenced_entity_name = N'table_that_contains_this_column';
```

This disregards application code entirely, as well as any code that is constructed using dynamic SQL, and any code that is based off of that column indirectly. Don't forget about SSIS packages, SSRS reports, etc. which may have hard-coded this length too.